# Monitoring Google Cloud Platform with Statuspage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring

I want to integrate my Google Cloud Platform  to Statuspage by Atlassian. I've been thinking, how can I monitor my instance without an API setup in my application. I want to create a script for checking the server connection and setup API in the script maybe.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching around, it seems that indeed, it's not possible to integrate GCP with Atlassian StatusPage.

I believe that the best option for you would be to use the [Stackdriver Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring). As per the Google official documentation [Introduction to the Stackdriver Monitoring API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3):

> The Monitoring API v3 gives you access to over 1,000 Stackdriver Monitoring metrics from Google Cloud and Amazon Web Services. You can create your own custom metrics and can organize your cloud resources using groups.

I would recommend you to take a look at it, as it seems to be the best option for you to monitor your instance's health.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes you're right! as my explore in documentation and other question, i didn't found any recommendation at integrating both platform. Stackdriver is one of best method to do the monitoring to gcp instance, but I still need using the Statuspage as my monitoring/reporting tools to users and other developer. I've tried to make python script for testing connection and sending the Statuspage API incident when an event occurs. Its works well too.

Answer (score 0):

@gso_gabriel answer isn't correct. You can configure GCP *alerts* to trigger specific PagerDuty services. Then you can connect StatusPage to react to changes to PagerDuty.

To do this, one could:

0. Create a StatusPage project, create all *services* to monitor
1. Create a PagerDuty project, create all *components* to monitor
2. Create a new *notification channel* on GCP using PagerDuty and add the generated service-key from PagerDuty, obtained when creating a new *service* and integrating it with StackDriver
3. Create a GCP *uptime check* and the relative *alert* using the PagerDuty channel.
4. Link PagerDuty to StatusPage through StatusPage *apps*
5. Configure the rules on the PagerDuty app on StatusPage
6. (optional) Configure the PagerDuty app on StatusPage and edit the *rules* to open and close incidents based on pre-created *templates*.

Answer (score 0):

I actually came across the same problem a while back and decided to write a cloud function that can open and resolve incidents in Atlassian's Statuspage.

Here's the repo https://github.com/snoofa-com/statuspage-and-gcp-monitoring

[image]

You can configure the incident using the policy's User labels and Documentation blocks.